# Replacements for Adobe Flash's hitTestObject Method

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, collision-detection

so I've recently had problems with using `hitTestObject`. I did a bit of research about `hitTestPoint` and that is too exact. And, using the `bitmap` is a bit too complicated for me.

Is there any other user-made collision detection functions? If so, how would I use it? I am trying to test if the object `eChar` collides with an objecy called `bd1`. I've found one, but that required my code to be in a class, which it isn't (it's programmed in the action window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very popular API is [PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.](http://anotherearlymorning.com/files/PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.as)

All you do is import it (`import PixelPerfectCollisionDetection;`) and check collisions like:

`if(PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.isColliding(eChar, bd1, commonParent, pixelPrecise (set to True for Pixel detections), tolerance:Number = 0 (for testing if testing for same Alpha) ))` which either returns `true` or `false`

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll go try it out. Can youy give me a quick sample text with testing if eChar collids with bd1?

Comment: @user2789610 `if(PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.isColliding(eChar, bd1, MovieClip(root), true)) { /* Do whatever if colliding */ }else { /* Do whatever if not colliding */ }`

Comment: Thanks! Although I just ran the program to test it and the '.as' file for the collision detection gives me errors... :\                             EDIT: I'm making an android app with flash, is that helps....

Comment: @user2789610 Where it says 'package', change that to match the location of the file

Comment: I still get the errors, although I'm not sure if I did it right. Currently I have this, so I'm not sure if it should be in quotes, or...: package C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Flash Pro\PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.as

Comment: Make sure `PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.as` is in the same folder as your project, and let's say your file is in a folder called 'game' in 'Documents', you would have `package Documents/game`.  Then, in your fla file, you would have `import PixelPerfectCollisionDetection`

Comment: so without the C:\user\... part? Also, it seems to jsut be syntax errors :\

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've upvoted all your comments. The problem still persists, and it says it a syntax error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DrsMXAngiRbtmlrmgCkANfNMbu_T1FPB4-0BU9GvoSQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user2789610 Will look into it, also upvoted comments have no effect ;)

Comment: @user2789610 Are you getting errors on `PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.as` or the other thing?

Comment: The PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.as is where the errors come from.

Comment: @user2789610 Can you please send me a link to what your new `PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.as` file looks like?

Comment: Here you are: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KMZf5y8olpDtIUCSNO8n3ptZMC0nAlY1ES-QoPY9CRQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user2789610 You saved the file wrong.  You need to save it as an `as` file, it has **html** in it.  Replace all your code there with the code here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/17IPf75xOU0LbF2qTEXMVyjT_f3gcYjOHnQdaXYSG-Kc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, this solves just about everything. Except for: Line 1, Column 15 1084: Syntax error: expecting leftbrace before div.
This refers to the column 15, where the'/' is between coding & flashpro.

Comment: @user2789610 Actually, since the file is in the root directory, you don't need anything there.  Just put 'package', remove coding and / and flashpro.